# When I send a post request in android it return nothing. When I send post request to my server it displays the write thing

Tags: java, php, android, post

I am beginner to android when I send post request the string return is empty(I confirm it from the log). But when I send online post request through [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it) it returns true(in my case which is actually right). Why it is returning empty string I don't found any mistake in my php code as well android.
android code:

```
    package com.example.harshitbatra.hammertime;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

/**
 * Created by Harshit Batra on 06-07-2016.
 */
public class Signupasync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String username,phone,address,email,password;
    String url;

    private postexecutelistener myListener;

    public Signupasync(postexecutelistener pel,String url,String username, String phone,String address,String email,String password )
    {
        myListener = pel;
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public interface postexecutelistener
    {
        public void postexecutedone(String str);
    }

    public String connect()
    {
        HashMap<String,String> hash = new HashMap<>(6);
        hash.put("usernamekey",username);
        hash.put("phonekey",phone);
        hash.put("addresskey",address);
        hash.put("emailkey",email);
        hash.put("passwordkey",password);

        return performPostCall(url,hash);

    }

    public String performPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams)
    {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try
        {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response += line;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response = "";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet())
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        Log.e("dsasd", "getPostDataString: " + result);
        return result.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... para)
    {
        return connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(str);
        Log.d("jsdk", "String from signup.php " + str);
        myListener.postexecutedone(str);
    }

}
```

php code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.in","u626717580_batra","hb99960","u626717580_mydb");


if($con)
{

    $username = $_POST['usernamekey'];
    $phone = $_POST['phonekey'];
    $address = $_POST['addresskey'];
    $email = $_POST['emailkey'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordkey'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO  `u626717580_mydb`.`signup` (
    `username` ,
    `phone` ,
    `address` ,
    `email` ,
    `password`
    )
    VALUES (
    '$username',  '$phone',  '$address',  '$email',  '$password'
    );
    ";          

    if($username)
    {
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql) )
        echo "true";
        else
        echo "false";   
    }

}
```

logs:

```
 W: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "hb99960.esy.es": No address associated with hostname
W:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
W:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
W:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
W:     at com.example.harshitbatra.hammertime.Signupasync.performPostCall(Signupasync.java:79)
W:     at com.example.harshitbatra.hammertime.Signupasync.connect(Signupasync.java:58)
W:     at com.example.harshitbatra.hammertime.Signupasync.doInBackground(Signupasync.java:134)
W:     at com.example.harshitbatra.hammertime.Signupasync.doInBackground(Signupasync.java:26)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W: Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W:     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
W:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
W:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
W:  ... 21 more
W: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
W:  ... 24 more    
D: String from signup.php 

 last line "String from signup.php" is empty.
```

Comment: Could you post the complete log trace. Would be helpful.

Comment: @nitinsh99 you can see the logs. anything else you want to know?

Comment: As you can see in the stack trace Your Android code is not able to reach the  server hosting your PHP i.e hb99960.esy.es. Are you sure that your Android device and the PC from which you were trying out "hurl.it" is on the same network?

Comment: Are you sure that the `URL` that you're using is correct ? Also, are you sure the device is connected to the internet ?

Comment: both devices are connected to same wifi

Comment: yes device is connected to internet properly

Comment: url is also correct @nitinsh99

Comment: I am assuming you are trying it out on a device and not on an emulator. Correct me if I am wrong. Could you confrim by hitting "hb99960.esy.es" from a browser on this device?

Comment: figure  out  thanks @nitinsh99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the stack trace Your Android code is not able to reach the server hosting your PHP i.e hb99960.esy.es. Are you sure that your Android device and the PC from which you were trying out "hurl.it" is on the same network.

Make sure you are able to reach "hb99960.esy.es" from a browser on your device/emulator.

Hope it helps